# select rows with specific value in the second column

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner in bash. I have a .csv file. It contains 2 columns (Name and Num). Here is the content of columns:

```
Name, Num 
ex1, 10.20.30.40 
ex2, 20.30.40.30 
ex3, 10.45.60.20 
ex4, 10.20.30.40
```

I want to select the rows that their 2nd column is equal to $Number (For example "10.20.30.40"). I use this script:

```
awk -F, '$2 == $Number' name.csv >output.txt
```

but after executing the code, "output.txt" is empty. When I echo the found values, it doesn't show anything either. What's wrong?

I also want to access to the value that is stored in the first column of this row. How should I do this?

Comment: You should try like `Number="10.20.30.40";awk -v num="$Number" -F', ' '$2 == num' file > output.txt`?

Comment: It's *kind of* a CSV file; your delimiter is `, `, not `,`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The output file contains only one line, while I had multiple lines with Number="10.20.30.40" in my original file.

Comment: please update the question with an example value for `$Number` and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

a simple `grep` could do what you need - the below will output the whole line of the matching string into the `output.txt` file :

```
grep "$Number" name.csv > output.txt
```

Comment: but it only gave me one of these lines while I have multiple lines with Number="10.20.30.40"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Number='^.\{3\}, 10\.20\.30\.40'
grep "$Number" yourfile.csv > output.txt
```

Comment: it displayed this error: grep: 10.20.30.40: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry, the order of grep params was inverted. Now it is ok, thanks

Comment: The output file contains only one line, while I had multiple lines with Number="10.20.30.40" in my original file.

Comment: It should be ok now

Comment: You should escape the periods, or you'll also match something like `10920930940`.